# Can subclass methods return a different type than the abstract class in python?

Tags: python, abstract-class, subclass

Is this acceptable?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any


class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def test(self) -> Any:
        ...
    
    
class B(A):
    def test(self) -> int:
        return 1
    
class C(A):
    def test(self) -> str:
        return "yes"
```

To clarify, I know they *can*, I just want to know if this is acceptable in terms of good practices.

Comment: *More specific*, yes, but not different. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science).

Comment: Yes, they can. Did you *try* it? What do you mean by "acceptable", precisely?

Comment: @jonrsharpe well, they *can* return whatever they want.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sure, but e.g. MyPy will shout at you!

Comment: If your abstract class specifically defines that `Any` return type is acceptable, then this is acceptable. The subclasses just shouldn't *break* expectations, e.g. returning an `int` when the abstract interface says it should be a `str`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sure, but my point is, it isn't clear that is what the OP is asking. EDIT: actually with `Any` I think it would pass mypy

Comment: Be aware that "is acceptable in terms of good practices" is borderline opinion based. *In theory* classes should be well-behaved according to LSP and such. *In practice* Python itself is more about practicality than purity and violates this left and right as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes, but it would be much better to define a generic return type and have the subclasses return subclasses of this return type.

For example, you could define a class `GenericType` and have two subclasses `GenericTypeA` and `GenericTypeB`. Then you could do something like this:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def test(self) -> GenericType:
        ...
    
    
class B(A):
    def test(self) -> GenericTypeA:
        ...
    
class C(A):
    def test(self) -> GenericTypeB:
        ...
```

This way class A is telling the user that the test method always returns a `GenericType` object, which is itself an abstract class. That way the user knows that any subclass of class A will return a subclass of `GenericType`.

Comment: Subclassing seems like overkill. Any subtype, be it inherited, structural or virtual, would do. Which comes full-circle back to the question, which is about returning a type *not* defining the concrete types.